# Get area size from geom_area (discrete values)

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I would like to get the area under a curve using ggplot2. The problem is that I have just discrete values (measurements, dependent variable) on a continuous scale (time), but measurements are not equally distant. I am not interested in fitting a function (I tried for analysis) but just the area under the plot.

I know I could calculate means between x values and then do the "discrete integral". But I thought there might be an easier way to get just the area size, because I manage to draw the entire thing in ggplot2 using `geom_area`. So I get a neatly filled area, but is there any possibility of extracting the area size from `geom_area`?

**EDIT:** Below are some nice solutions to how to calculate the area under a curve where only discrete values are given. Still, if anyone knows if it's possible to extract the area size simply by `geom_area` I'm super curious to know!

Reproducible example:

```
mydata <- data.frame(time = c(2,4,6,8,19,24,30,43,48,69),
                     ratio = c(0.24, 1.04, 1.08, 1.27, 2.12, 2.13, 2.34, 2.00, 1.90, 1.96))

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = time, y = ratio))+
  geom_area(fill = "grey")+
  geom_point(colour = "red")+
  labs(title = "My sample data", y = "Ratio", x = "Time")
```

[image]

Comment: found a simple approach, which may be used with caution as I am not 100% sure if this function acts the same way- looks though as it does:
`auc` from package `flux` (also in `AUC`) - calculates area under the curve for given `x` and `y`. In the desctription I read it uses the trapezoidal rule, which seems to approximate in the same way as @Axeman did.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the area of the grey polygon between subsequent points. It consists of two shapes,

- A rectagle with a height from y = 0 up to the lower of the two y values, with width x1 - x0.
- A triangle with a height that is the difference between y0 and y1, and width x1 - x0.

[image]

If we calculate those areas for each subsequent pair of points, we can sum those together for the total area.

```
mydata %>% 
  arrange(time) %>% 
  mutate(area_rectangle = (lead(time) - time) * pmin(ratio, lead(ratio)),
         area_triangle = 0.5 * (lead(time) - time) * abs(ratio - lead(ratio))) %>% 
  summarise(area = sum(area_rectangle + area_triangle, na.rm = TRUE))
```

> ```
>     area
> 1 126.92
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand the mathematics as this was how I thought doing it first, but then didn't know how to do that smartly in R. Played around with loops but didn't trust my results. So your code looks nicely short, however I tried it out and it didn't work...is `lead` your own function? What does `%>%` mean?

Comment: `lead` is in `dplyr`. The `%>%` is a pipe to chain functions together. I.e. `f(a, b)` is the same as `a %>% f(b)`.

Comment: Got it. seems to be a big package, my notebook can't handle it right now...so gotta try later. Anyways, thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

We can compute the area with *integration*, by summing the areas under the lines too, as illustrated in the below code and the figures:

```
mydata <- data.frame(time = c(2,4,6,8,19,24,30,43,48,69),
                     ratio = c(0.24, 1.04, 1.08, 1.27, 2.12, 2.13, 2.34, 2.00, 1.90, 1.96))

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = time, y = ratio))+
  geom_area(fill = "grey")+
  geom_point(colour = "red")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=mydata$time) + 
  labs(title = "My sample data", y = "Ratio", x = "Time")
```

[image]

```
get.line.slope <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
}

get.line.intercept <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  y1 - (y2 - y1)*x1 / (x2 - x1)
}

st.lines <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(1:(nrow(mydata)-1), 
  function(i) c(
    m=get.line.slope(mydata$time[i],mydata$ratio[i], mydata$time[i+1], mydata$ratio[i+1]),
    c=get.line.intercept(mydata$time[i],mydata$ratio[i], mydata$time[i+1], mydata$ratio[i+1]),
    startx=mydata$time[i],
    endx=mydata$time[i+1]))))   

st.lines # as can be seen there are 9 st. lines with slope m, intercept c
# we have to find the area under each line from left vertical line at startx to 
# right vertical line at endx

#              m          c startx endx
# 1  0.400000000 -0.5600000      2    4
# 2  0.020000000  0.9600000      4    6
# 3  0.095000000  0.5100000      6    8
# 4  0.077272727  0.6518182      8   19
# 5  0.002000000  2.0820000     19   24
# 6  0.035000000  1.2900000     24   30
# 7 -0.026153846  3.1246154     30   43
# 8 -0.020000000  2.8600000     43   48
# 9  0.002857143  1.7628571     48   69

ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = time, y = ratio))+
  geom_area(fill = "grey")+
  geom_point(colour = "red")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=mydata$time) + 
  geom_abline(data=st.lines, aes(slope=m, intercept=c), col='blue', lty=2) +
  labs(title = "My sample data", y = "Ratio", x = "Time")
```

[image]

```
# compute the area under each of the blue dotted lines in between the black vertical lines
areas <- apply(st.lines, 1, function(l) 
         integrate(f=function(x)l['m']*x+l['c'], 
         lower = l['startx'], upper=l['endx'])$value)
areas
# [1]  1.280  2.120  2.350 18.645 10.625 13.410 28.210  9.750 40.530

# total area under the polygon
sum(areas)
# [1] 126.92
```

Comment: wow, what a code! I'm impressed of how many different approaches there are. To be honest, I'll stick to the easier/faster solutions above, as I have to calculate the are a few times... thanks anyway for the effort!

Comment: Thanks @Spreeprinte, but the above code is fast and also conceptually easy to understand I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function [trapz](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/trapz) from pracma package, and you can get the same result as above.

```
library(pracma)

mydata <- data.frame(time = c(2,4,6,8,19,24,30,43,48,69),
                     ratio = c(0.24, 1.04, 1.08, 1.27, 2.12, 2.13, 2.34, 2.00, 1.90, 1.96))

#for cumulative areas

cumtrapz(mydata$time, mydata$ratio)

         [,1]
 [1,]   0.000
 [2,]   1.280
 [3,]   3.400
 [4,]   5.750
 [5,]  24.395
 [6,]  35.020
 [7,]  48.430
 [8,]  76.640
 [9,]  86.390
 [10,] 126.920


#for total area

trapz(mydata$time, mydata$ratio)

[1] 126.92
```